# Spark: How much executor memory is available for application use?

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing an algorithm that processes a "chunk" of data in memory.  I'm using JavaPairRDD.groupByKey() to designate the chunks, but it is unclear to me how to calculate the optimal chunk size. The large it is, the faster the algo will run.  Given the chunk size, I can estimate my memory use, but how much executor memory is actually available to me (as opposed to, claimed by Spark for its own use)?  And is there any way to programmatically suggest to Spark that I have a memory-intensive step in the transformation chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apache-spark-memory-management-deep-dive-deepak-rajak) explains it really well. You get
`(HeapSize – ReservedMemory) * (1.0 – spark.memory.fraction)`
which for a 4GB heap is about 1500MB assuming default settings for other parameters.